# different permalink tips in using wp_query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I used wp_query to show titles of my recent posts in sidebar of single posts.
but i face with a strange problem, when permalink is like `http://my-site/?p=12` it works correctly but when permalink is like `http://my-site/2012/09/22/sample-post/` it don't work correctly and only shows titles of posts that publish after current post.

what's the problem?

Comment: What is the code that you are using to show the titles?

Comment: @doublesharp recent post that is in widget items

Comment: There should be no difference based on the URL structure that you use - both are resolved to the post_ID. It is possible that you are seeing cached data as this widget will use cached results if they are available. You can see the code in /wp-includes/default-widgets.php line 544-584 (Wordpress 3.4.2)